# 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.\r\n', None

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am trying to have a Python script stage a file to a locally hosted Git:

```
gitExe = r"C:\Git\bin\git.exe"
gitdir = r' --git-dir="G:\QA\.git"'
worktree = r' --work-tree="G:\QA\"'
gitcmd = " add"
myCsv = "Reports.csv"

import subprocess

print gitdir
print gitcmd
print gitExe

cmd = 'C:\\Git\\bin\\git.exe --git-dir="G:\\QA\\.git" --work-tree="G:\\QA" add Reports.csv' ####WORKS####
#cmd = ['C:\\Git\\bin\\git.exe --git-dir="G:\\QA\\.git" --work-tree="G:\\QA" add Reports.csv'] ####DOESNT WORK####
#cmd = ['C:\\Git\\bin\\git.exe --git-dir="G:\\QA\\.git" --work-tree="G:\\QA" add Reports.csv'+""] ####DOESNT WORK####
#cmd = [gitExe + gitdir + worktree + gitcmd + myCsv] ####DOESNT WORK####
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print cmd
print p.communicate()
```

When I pass the full command as a string (uncommendted line above) everything works fine but when I pass it as an array (the three commented out lines above) I get the following error message:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
 --git-dir="G:\QA\.git"
 add
C:\Git\bin\git.exe
['C:\\Git\\bin\\git.exe --git-dir="G:\\QA\\.git" --work-tree="G:\\QA\\" addReports.csv']
('The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.\r\n', None)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the command as an array, each parameter must be a separate element.

```
cmd = ['C:\\Git\\bin\\git.exe', '--git-dir="G:\\QA\\.git"', '--work-tree="G:\\QA"',
    'add', 'Reports.csv']
```

The first item in the array is the program name. In your case, python tried to make the entire command line into the program name.